# "Unsupported Graphics Card" in Epic Games Launcher (GTX 1080)

Tags: technical-issues, windows, fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world, epic-games-launcher

I'm trying to play Fortnite on my PC but it does not work. When I install the *Epic Games Launcher* (I'm on Windows 10) it throws the error:

> There is a problem with your graphics card. Please ensure your card meets the minimum system requirements and that you have the latest drivers installed.

I have an NVIDIA GTX 1080, so it certainly meets the minimum system requirements. The drivers are also up-to-date (I just  checked from *GeForce Experience*) and all other games work perfectly.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

**UPDATE:** apparently Steam Big Picture is **very** laggy, it runs at 1080p maximum and it says I'm running with "Microsoft Basic Render Driver 0 bytes", as if drivers were not installed. This doesn't make sense because - for instance - The Witcher 3 runs at High in 4k at decent framerate.

**UPDATE #2:** now all 3D apps are crashing. I don't know what TH is going on. Windows Update also just failed, dunno if related

**UPDATE #3**: I switched my GPU to the Intel Integrated Graphics from BIOS, then I moved my DP cable to the Mobo port and started Windows. At first, Steam still recognised the GPU as "Microsoft Basic Render Driver", but - after installing Intel Video Drivers - Steam detected my integrated 530 GPU correctly. I started a game with very low graphics settings (I didn't have my GTX 1080 enabled so graphics were weak) and it didn't have any issue. After reverting back to NVIDIA graphics, Steam still seems to be using the iGPU. Games will sometimes crash and sometimes work with the NVIDIA GPU, in some cases (e.g. The Witcher 2 Enhanced Edition) a window will pop up saying that Direct3D 9.0 couldn't be initialized. Witcher 3 works though (unless Steam BPM is also running). I guess I screwed up my install and I'll have to resort to a C: wipe... Oh, and - quite ironically - Fortnite is one of the few things to work!

[image: a screengrab of the error in question]

Comment: Is the integrated GPU disabled? Do you have any 3rd party software messing with your display settings?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with hybrid graphics. Are you playing on a laptop? If so, you might need to force the launcher to use your GTX 1080 instead of the iGP.

Comment: @Nolonar nope, this is a desktop PC and I'm running with a DP cable attached to the Card. It is also set as primary in BIOS

Comment: Check your PC with Antivirus/malwarebytes; run CCleaner on your registry multiple times; make sure that your graphic card is not loose. If all that doesn't help, reinstall windows and make sure to only install what you really need and not some random stuff

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Have checked all of this, and it looks fine. I repaired my C:\ drive because CHKDSK reported that it had to be done. The Witcher 3 now starts, so does Minecraft, but the Big Picture Mode issue is still present, as well as the Windows Update error

Comment: What is the exact error for the windows update? Have you tried reinstalling steam big picture?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The error is 0x80092004 and yes, I just reinstalled Steam and all games anew, no change. I've looked on the internet and both the errors don't seem to be common. As far as the original issue is concerned, I have been able to start the launcher using the -OpenGL parameter, but it will just try to update itself and fail with the same error as the one in the question

Comment: @XtremeBaumer hmm... I dunno why but this looks like some sort of auto-generated "scam" website. I had stumbled upon that already and it seems to more or less follow the modus operandi of other "malware fixing" sites. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @alex2003super yeah just checked it. It seems to be some kind of malware. Anyways, if you can't repair your registry , then you should definitly reinstall Windows

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Well, this is bad news. Since my mobo has some RAM issues and I'm going to rebuild my system with a new mobo and CPU when I'll have some time for this, I guess I'll just wait until I have a new build and reinstall the system then, because I don't want to deal with driver uninstallation crap either. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Umm, maybe the RAM issues are the cause for this trouble as well. If you know which RAM it is exaclty, you could try to remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75211/discussion-between-alex2003super-and-xtremebaumer).

Comment: I had the same problem with my GTX 560 Ti, and on my system, the culprit was "Duet Display", an app that connects to an iPad and uses it as a second screen. Uninstalling it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU driver subsystem was completely broken in my install of Windows. I had no choice but to reinstall Microsoft Windows altogether, as neither DDU nor GFE could fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Put `-opengl` in shortcut after `launcher.exe` (`foo/launcher.exe -opengl`). Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your graphics card is actually loaded. Are integrated graphics enabled somehow? See if you can trace what software is messing around with your Graphics Card. If you aren't a casual gamer then you might've not set it up yet.

If possible, try installing the graphic card by right clicking on the start menu, and pressing "device manager", and right click on the unsupported graphics card. :-)

**== Edit ==**

I don't know much about Windows as I am a Linux user but see if you can find the original file where the launcher is at (.exe file) and try to run it with the command prompt. If its the installer do the same thing in the command prompt where the installer file is like this

```
c:\> REPLACE_WITH_INSTALLER.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the card seems to have drivers installed (and running with G-Sync) but all 3D apps are now crashing

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem with Fortnite. I had mistakenly installed the new Graphics card (Radeon 550) without disabling the built-in Intel HD 2000 card . 
The solution was to shut down, plug out the new card, start, disable the intel card in device manager -》display adapter, then shut down, plug in the radeon card. This solved the issue. I have Windows 7, 64 bit.

Answer (score -2):

Go to GeForce Expirence and reinstall the latest driver update.

Comment: First thing I tried

Answer (score -3):

try this, i guarantee it's work

Comment: Videos are not answers here at Arqade.  Please summarize the relevant information from the video, so that if the video ever goes down, your answer is still valid.